# How to make a redirect and keep the query string?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, wsgi, webapp2

I want to make a redirect and keep what is the query string. Something like `self.redirect` plus the query parameters that was sent. Is that possible?

Comment: Where do you want to keep it? In a session?

Comment: Can't I just pass on the query parameters via HTTP GET?

Comment: Of course, I don't know which framework you are using, but that should be straightforward. In straight http you would send a 301 or 303 with the Location header set to the redirect url plus the query params you want to keep.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do and I think it is straightforward. I use webapp2 and google app engine, I'm adding those tags to the question.

Comment: @Wooble I could try the parameters one by one but I'm looking for a way to add the entire query string in a oneliner. I know the names of the parameters I want to get via HTTP GET and I want to pass on their values. I figure there should be a way to pass on the entire map instead of one variable at a time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
newurl = '/my/new/route?' + urllib.urlencode(self.request.params)
self.redirect(newurl)
```

Comment: can not run in tornado 4

Comment: Can use `urllib.parse.urlencode(self.request.query_arguments, doseq=True)` in then new version.

Answer (score 11):

You can fetch the query string to the current request with `self.request.query_string`; thus you can redirect to a new URL with `self.redirect('/new/url?' + self.request.query_string)`.

Comment: can not run in tornado 4

Answer (score 5):

Use the `RedirectView`.

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
path('go-to-django/', RedirectView.as_view(url='https://djangoproject.com', query_string=True), name='go-to-django')
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in Django 2.2. The query string is available as a QueryDict instance `request.GET` for an HTTP GET and `request.POST` for an HTTP POST. Convert these to normal dictionaries and then use `urlencode`.

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode

query_string = urlencode(request.GET.dict())  # or request.GET.urlencode()

new_url = '/my/new/route' + '?' + query_string
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/.