# URL Query on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am applying specific styles in Worpdress when I access a certain URL, for example:

misiito.com/?mobile
When I enter there I hide the header and footer. My code is the following:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['mobile'] ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adaptabilidad', plugins_url( 'css/mobile.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0.0' );
}

if ( isset( $_GET['totem'] ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'adaptabilidad', plugins_url( 'css/totems.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0.0' );
}
```

**My problem is that it doesn't change the links and places the /?mobile, please help me, how can I do it?**
That is, I want all the buttons at the end to have /?mobile

I tried this, but it's obviously a bug:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'adaptabilidad_nattule_add_mobile_url' );
    function adaptabilidad_nattule_add_mobile_url( $content ) {
        $content = str_replace( 'href="', 'href="?mobile', $content );
        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: "My problem is that it doesn't change the links and places the /?mobile" - what have you tried to achieve that? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I honestly don't know what to do, but look at the update I just posted.

Comment: Please share more details. Which kind of link do you want to modify?

Comment: All the links on my website that lead to other pages, for example, I am on the home page and there is a button that leads to the contact page, I want that contact button to have /?mobile at the end

Comment: Some help?  I still can't think of a way to know what the URL is to add the new example: href=' URL + "/mobile" '

Answer (score 0):

It's just a suggestion, but have you thought of creating duplicate pages (for each styles) with different URL slugs and simply using a plugin like "Simple 301 Redirects" to associate them with a "/something"?

Example:
yousite.com/page1-style2
yousite.com/page1-style27

Comment: I understood that you want me to do a 301 redirect, but honestly it was not clear to me. I'll explain, I'm on the link that ends with /?mobile, and if I go to another link like /contact, I want that to end with /?mobile, the same with all links. Because what I am doing is hiding the header and footer from my webview app, if I send the app to a link that does not have the header hidden with ?mobile it would not make sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569768/how-to-make-a-redirect-and-keep-the-query-string

Comment: I misunderstood your question